# Lookup Values in one column and if match add the values from a different column Google Script Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a script that will go thru all the values of one column and add the quantities of the matching column.

Then copy at the bottom of the table the results, something like this:

Blue    1
Green   2
Green   5
Red     2
Blue    4

Results:
Blue    5
Green   7
Red     2

[image]

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countingBuckets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('b');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var cb={bA:[]};
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!cb.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][0])) {
      cb[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
      cb.bA.push(vA[i][0]);
    }else{
      cb[vA[i][0]]+=vA[i][1];
    }  
  });
  sh.appendRow(["Results"]);
  cb.bA.forEach(function(e,i){
    sh.appendRow([e,cb[e]]);
  });
}

function countingBuckets() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('b');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var cb={bA:[]};
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(!cb.hasOwnProperty(vA[i][0])) {
      cb[vA[i][0]]={cells:0,sum:0};
      cb[vA[i][0]].sum=vA[i][1];
      cb[vA[i][0]].cells=1;
      cb.bA.push(vA[i][0]);
    }else{
      cb[vA[i][0]].sum+=vA[i][1];
      cb[vA[i][0]].cells+=1;
    }  
  });
  sh.appendRow(["Results"]);
  cb.bA.forEach(function(e,i){
    sh.appendRow([e,cb[e].sum,cb[e].cells]);
  });
}
```

[Javascript Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: what if I want to count the cells too?: Blue 2, Green 2, Red 1

Answer (score 1):

With formula, you can use this:

```
= filter
  (
     { unique(A1:A),
       sumif(A1:A,"=" & UNIQUE(A1:A),B1:B)
     }
     , unique(A1:A)<>""
  )
```

[image]